# Made Up Puzzle #1

Tags: riddle

Cool, new pokemon
Happy or sad
I am bored
Lol, this is a joke
Disgusting

This riddle might be easy due to the fact I made it up on the spot.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! (Take the **[Tour]!**)  I'm glad you're eager to contribute here, but you appear to be struggling a little. May I suggest you take your time to *create* (not just *find*) a well crafted puzzle or riddle, and not dash something off hastily in an attempt to participate? You may benefit from looking around the site, and in particular checking out the high voted puzzles in the tags that appeal to you, to get a better sense of what kinds of puzzles work best here. Welcome again, and hope your next puzzle sees great success!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it

> CHILD

Because

> Just pick the capital letters.

Comment: good job,knew it was not too chalanging.

Comment: Am using it for a Choose your own adventure story